# Selected Views and passing data to another activity

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button, android-spinner

[image]

This is my printScreen:
I would like to know how can i show the list of Dentists according to all selected criterions ,when i clicked the button"Voir La Liste"

Comment: What have you implemented?

Comment: use Intent Bundle to send data to next Activity..